# Recursive int method that returns number from String

Tags: java, recursion

I try write recursive method that accepts a string and returns a number representing the hashCode:
Our hashCode number is obtained by summing all the ASCII numbers of the string,
After each character represents a certain ASCII number.
(R) 82 + (e) 101 + (d) 100 = 219 Number "RED" returns a string with method: for example

```
public int hashCode(String value) {

final int prime = 31;
int result = 1;
result = prime * result + x; //NOT recognize
result = prime * result + y; //NOT recognize

if(value.length() == 0){
    return 0;
}
    return value.charAt(0)+hashCode(value.substring(1))
     }
```

How the recursive work each char?
Thanks

Comment: What recursion?

Comment: Recursion is very much *not* appropriate for this problem.

Comment: That what my lecture ask. I know it's not the best to this... And the use of hash Code unnecessary.

Comment: There's no `unsigned int` type in Java. And you can't return two things. This code does not make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously you came to this site for helping in school task.
Anyway, I'd try to explain how recursive methods works.
Shortly, the method calls itself, but that calls cannot be infinite, so you should to decide **when** the calls stops.

Let's consider the sum of char in String recursively achieved.
Example:

- `String test = "";` (empty String). Your method can return 0.
- `String test = "R";` The method should return codePoint of "R"
- `String test = "Red";` The method should return code point of "R" + sum of codePoints of chars in remaining String ("ed").

Look at the simplified code:

```
public class Helper {

    private static int recursiveSumOfChars(String input){
        if(input.length() == 0) return 0;
        if(input.length() == 1) return input.codePointAt(0);
        else return input.codePointAt(0) + recursiveSumOfChars(input.substring(1));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String test = "Red";
        System.out.println(recursiveSumOfChars(test));
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, if you found this answer helpful, consider to accept it, or up vote, so the other users can benefit from it.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want something similar to this

```
 public int hashCode(String value) {

final int prime = 31;
int result = 1;
result = prime * result + x;
result = prime * result + y;

if(value.length() == 0){
    return 0;
}

    return value.charAt(0)+hashCode(value.substring(1))
     }
```

`

Comment: i assumed you declared them just declare them inside for example with int x=0,y=0; it gave the exact values you wanted